# How to pass a variable between JPanel classes?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a JTabbedPane with two JPanels that need to stay in seperate classes. In PageOne, I want to be able to increment MyInteger by clicking the add button, and I then want to be able to print that integer in PageTwo by clicking the button there. It prints the correct value in PageOne, but prints 0 when I pass it to the PageTwo class and print it there.

How can I pass the value in such a way that it prints the correct value when clicking the button in both JPanels? I figure it has something to do with how I inherit from PageOne, but couldn't find a way of changing it on SO that solved my problem.

Main class:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyJFrame {

    PageOne pageOne;
    PageTwo pageTwo;

    public MyJFrame() {

        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        pageOne = new PageOne();
        pageTwo = new PageTwo();

        JTabbedPane jTabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

        jTabbedPane.addTab("Page One", pageOne);
        jTabbedPane.addTab("Page Two", pageTwo);

        f.add(jTabbedPane);
        f.setSize(200,120);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new MyJFrame();

    }
}
```

JPanel One:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class PageOne extends JPanel {

    public Integer myInteger = 0;
    public JButton add;

    public PageOne() {

        add = new JButton();
        add.setText("Increment number");

        add(add);

        add.addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
            myInteger++;
            printOne();
        });

    }

    public void printOne() {
        System.out.println("Page One:" + myInteger);
    }

}
```

JPanel Two:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class PageTwo extends JPanel {

    PageOne  pageOneRef = new PageOne();
    public JButton button;

    public PageTwo() {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        button = new JButton("Click me");

        panel.add(button);
        add(panel);

        button.addActionListener(e -> printTwo());
    }

    public void printTwo() {
        System.out.println("Page Two:" + pageOneRef.myInteger);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating two `PageOne` objects: one inside `PageTwo` and one in the frame's constructor. Then `PageTwo` is referring to one of those (which is not the correct one).

Comment: The short answer is, you don't, or at least not the way you're trying to do.  Instead, you define a common model which can be shared between the components

Answer (score 2):

The basic answer is, you need some kind of "container" which can be shared between the two components.  This is commonly achieved through the use of a "model" of some kind.

See:

- [Model-View-Controller](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mvc-design-pattern/)
- [Observer Pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html)
- [Writing Event Listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html)

for an overview of the concepts presented below

## Runnable example

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();

                DefaultIntegerModel model = new DefaultIntegerModel();
                JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
                tabbedPane.addTab("Page One", new PageOne(model));
                tabbedPane.addTab("Page Two", new PageTwo(model));

                frame.add(tabbedPane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface IntegerModel {
        public interface Observer {
            public void valueDidChange(IntegerModel source, int value);
        }
        public int getValue();
        public void addObserver(Observer observer);
        public void removeObserver(Observer observer);
    }

    public interface MutableIntegerModel extends IntegerModel {

        public void setValue(int value);
    }

    public class DefaultIntegerModel implements MutableIntegerModel {

        private int value;

        private List<Observer> observers;

        public DefaultIntegerModel() {
            this(0);
        }

        public DefaultIntegerModel(int value) {
            this.value = value;
            observers = new ArrayList<Observer>(8);
        }

        @Override
        public void setValue(int value) {
            this.value = value;
            fireValueDidChange(value);
        }

        @Override
        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public void addObserver(Observer observer) {
            observers.add(observer);
        }

        @Override
        public void removeObserver(Observer observer) {
            observers.remove(observer);
        }

        protected void fireValueDidChange(int value) {
            for (Observer observer : observers) {
                observer.valueDidChange(this, value);
            }
        }
    }

    public class PageOne extends JPanel {

        public JButton add;

        private MutableIntegerModel model;

        public PageOne(MutableIntegerModel model) {
            this.model = model;

            add = new JButton();
            add.setText("Increment number");

            add(add);

            add.addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
                model.setValue(model.getValue() + 1);
                printOne();
            });

        }

        public void printOne() {
            System.out.println("Page One:" + model.getValue());
        }

    }

    public class PageTwo extends JPanel {

        private JButton button;
        private JLabel label;
        private IntegerModel model;

        public PageTwo(IntegerModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            model.addObserver(new IntegerModel.Observer() {
                @Override
                public void valueDidChange(IntegerModel source, int value) {
                    System.out.println("Page two value did change to " + value);
                    label.setText(Integer.toString(model.getValue()));
                }
            });

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            label = new JLabel(Integer.toString(model.getValue()));
            add(label, gbc);

            button = new JButton("Click me");
            button.addActionListener(e -> printTwo());
            add(button, gbc);
        }

        public void printTwo() {
            System.out.println("Page Two:" + model.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

> But why are there two models

Stop for a second and think about the responsibilities of each component.

`PageOne` want's to update the model, in order to do so, it also needs to know the value of the model.  The model makes no assumption about "how" the consumer of this model will do that (so I didn't provide a `increment` method), it just allows the consumer to set the value it wants

`PageTwo` just wants to display the value (and be notified when some change occurs), so it doesn't need a mutable version of the model.

This restricts what consumers maybe able to do to the model rather the exposing functionality to parties which don't need it (and might be tempted to abuse it)

This is a demonstration and your needs may differ, but I'm bit of a scrooge when I design these kinds of things, I need the consumers to prove to me that they need functionality, rather then "assuming" what functionality they "might" require

This is a practice known is "information hiding", which is supported by [Polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) in OO languages

Comment: Great answer. Personally I would additionally note that the [`Observable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) class could spare you from implementing the listeners' part on the model yourself, but that's just a minor change.

Comment: @gthanop Expected [`Observable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Observable.html) has been deprecated since Java9

Comment: omg, ok, hahaha. My bad.